# make an html element by javascropt

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want write a function to do creating an html tag
I have a input tag with and this function must add the value of this input to created html element and add a "x" to right of created element for remove element by click on it
but i can't add the 'x' button!

this is my script:

```
function myFunction() {
    x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
    var node = document.createElement("p");
    var node1 = document.createElement("button");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(x);
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("print").appendChild(node);
}
```

please help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create an element using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46681037/create-an-element-using-javascript)

Comment: no it shuold be without php and jquery

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536596/dynamically-creating-html-elements-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't provided any code, so I wrote the solution as per your problem's description. It looks like you are truing to create a todo list.
I have used the flexbox layout for proper alignment of the elements.

Here take a look at it:

```js
const textfield = document.querySelector('#textfield');
const addBtn = document.querySelector('#addBtn');
const list = document.querySelector('#list');

// add click listener
addBtn.addEventListener('click', addItemToList);

function addItemToList() {
    const value = textfield.value;
    if (value !== '') {
        const listNode = document.createElement('li');
        
        // add value in the span tag 
        const spanNode = document.createElement('span');
        spanNode.innerText = value;
        
        // create a delete button with value 'x' and add click listener
        const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
        deleteButton.innerText = 'x';
        deleteButton.addEventListener('click', deleteListNode)
        
        // add span and button inside the list node
        listNode.append(spanNode, deleteButton);
        
        // append list in the ul
        list.append(listNode);
    }
}

function deleteListNode(event) {
    target = event.target;
    
    // remove parent node i.e. <li> from dom
    target.parentElement.remove();
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  /* centerd alignment vertically and horizontally */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper {
    max-width: 20em;
}

#textfield, #list > li, #addBtn  {
    padding: 7px 10px;
    min-width: 70px;
}

ul {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

li {
  /* to create space between text and cross button  */
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>
        <input id="textfield" type="text"/>
        <button id="addBtn">Add</button>
    </div>
    <ul id="list">
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic function to create a HTML element (DIV) with the value of the input, create and append a button that will also remove element and button when clicked.

See comments in code...

```js
let el = document.getElementById('myinput');
let add = document.getElementById('add');
let cont = document.getElementById('cont');

// function to remove added element/s and button
const removeItems = (button, removeEl) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById(removeEl).remove();
    button.remove();
  });
}

function addDiv() {
  // set an increment
  let i = 1;
  // event listener on the input button for click
  add.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // create a div to hold the text input value
    let div = document.createElement("DIV");
    div.textContent = el.value;
    // set the div id and add a unique id using i
    div.setAttribute("id", `added_${i}`);
    div.style.padding = "5px";
    // append the parent container
    cont.append(div);
    // create the button element
    let button = document.createElement('BUTTON');
    // set the buttons textContent to X
    button.textContent = "X";
    // set the id attribute to a unique ID using i
    div.append(button);
    // call on the removal function
    removeItems(button, `added_${i}`);
    // increment the counter
    i++;
  });
}

// call function
addDiv();
```

```css
#cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #ddd;
}

button {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myinput">
<button id="add">add</button>
<div id="cont"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You created a button `node1` but never use it. Try this:

```
function myFunction() {
    x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
    var node = document.createElement("p");
    var node1 = document.createElement("button");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(x);
    node.appendChild(textnode);

    //create a text `'x'` inside this button
    node1.textContent = 'x';
    
    //append it to the `<p>` tag
    node.appendChild(node1);

    document.getElementById("print").appendChild(node);
}
```